# Attempt to create simple Contact gives error: PATCH requests require components to be updated

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

I am currently using SDK version `3.39.0` and version `0004` of the `API_MKT_CONTACT` service definition to create a new Contact in Marketing Cloud with the following code:

```
ContactOriginData contact =
        ContactOriginData.builder()
            .originOfContact(origin)
            .originTimestamp(ZonedDateTime.now())
            .externalContactID(pii.getId().toString())
            .firstName(pii.getFirstName())
            .lastName(pii.getLastName())
            .language(pii.getLanguage())
            .countryReg(pii.getRegion())
            .build();

// use low level API as a work around for https://github.com/SAP/cloud-sdk/issues/156
ODataRequestUpdate contactRequest = service
          .updateContactOriginData(contact)
          .withHeader("Sap-Cuan-RequestTimestamp", getFormattedTime(System.currentTimeMillis()))
          .withHeader("Sap-Cuan-SequenceId", "UpdatePatch")
          .withHeader("Sap-Cuan-SourceSystemType", "EXT")
          .withHeader("Sap-Cuan-SourceSystemId", "sdk-test")
          .toRequest();

String servicePath = "/sap/opu/odata/SAP/API_MKT_CONTACT_SRV;v=0004";
ODataRequestBatch requestBatch =  new ODataRequestBatch(servicePath, ODataProtocol.V2);
requestBatch.beginChangeset().addUpdate(contactRequest).endChangeset();
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientAccessor.getHttpClient(destination);
ODataRequestResultMultipartGeneric batchResult = requestBatch.execute(httpClient);
```

Running this produces the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "/IWFND/CM_MGW/096",
    "message": {
      "lang": "en",
      "value": "PATCH requests require components to be updated"
    },
    "innererror": {
      "application": {
        "component_id": "CEC-MKT-DM-IC",
        "service_namespace": "/SAP/",
        "service_id": "API_MKT_CONTACT_SRV",
        "service_version": "0004"
      },
      "transactionid": "3B63A2A6CC920630E0060492A51E7EE7",
      "timestamp": "20210310210334.4378960",
      "Error_Resolution": {
        "SAP_Transaction": "For backend administrators: use ADT feed reader \"SAP Gateway Error Log\" or run transaction /IWFND/ERROR_LOG on SAP Gateway hub system and search for entries with the timestamp above for more details",
        "SAP_Note": "See SAP Note 1797736 for error analysis (https://service.sap.com/sap/support/notes/1797736)",
        "Batch_SAP_Note": "See SAP Note 1869434 for details about working with $batch (https://service.sap.com/sap/support/notes/1869434)"
      },
      "errordetails": []
    }
  }
}
```

However, if I execute a similar request in postman it works without issue:

```
Request Payload:

--batch
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=changeset

--changeset
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

PATCH ContactOriginData(ContactOrigin='<ContactOrigin>',ContactID='24D8F7F6-440D-44F8-A24B-552435477688') HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 172
Sap-Cuan-RequestTimestamp: '2021-03-10T14:07:00.000'
Sap-Cuan-SequenceId: UpdatePatch
Sap-Cuan-SourceSystemType: EXT
Sap-Cuan-SourceSystemId: postman-test

{"OriginDataLastChgUTCDateTime":"/Date(1615410479885)/","EmailAddress":"samantha.cook@theoasis.com","FirstName":"Samantha","LastName":"Cook","Country":"US","Language":"EN"}

--changeset--
--batch--

Response Payload:

--1D7E85E6BC66B34E61ACF0EF3964CBD90
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=1D7E85E6BC66B34E61ACF0EF3964CBD91
Content-Length:       430

--1D7E85E6BC66B34E61ACF0EF3964CBD91
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Length: 262
content-transfer-encoding: binary

HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Content-Length: 0
dataserviceversion: 2.0
sap-message: {"code":"HPA_STAGING_AREA/037","message":"Payload is processed via staging area. See Import Monitor for details.","target":"","severity":"info","transition":false,"details":[]}


--1D7E85E6BC66B34E61ACF0EF3964CBD91--

--1D7E85E6BC66B34E61ACF0EF3964CBD90--
```

I should note that I have also tried using `.replacingEntity()` which doesn't work either and produces a completely different error:

```
Inline component is not defined or not allowed (HTTP PUT)
```

Is there something with the SDK that I am missing or not using correctly?
Any help would be appreciated!

Cheers!

Comment: Hi Kurts, I believe we might be checking if the sent-back payload has changed for performance improvements. This would at least explain why Postman works and SDK throws and error. Can you tell me if the payload you send and the original entity are the same? It'll speed up the investigation.

Comment: So for my case there is no original entity. My goal here is to create a brand new Contact. So the payload I send is not fetched from the service via `getContactOriginDataByKey()`. I'm building it from scratch before I send.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update an entity you should get it from the service first. That is regardless whether you are using:

1. `PATCH` which will update only changed fields
2. or `PUT` which will send the full entity object

Currently you are creating a new entity object via the builder: `ContactOriginData.builder()`. Instead, please use the corresponding `getContactOriginDataByKey()` method of your service to first retrieve the entity to update from the service. Actually many services will force you to do this to ensure you are always editing the latest version of your data. This often happens via [ETags which the SDK will also handle for you automatically](https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/java/features/odata/use-typed-odata-v2-client-in-sap-cloud-sdk-for-java#handling-of-etags).

You can find more information about the [update strategies from the SDK on the documentaiton](https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/java/features/odata/use-typed-odata-v2-client-in-sap-cloud-sdk-for-java#entity-update-strategies).

---

Edit:
As you pointed out in the comments the actual goal is to *create* an entity and the specific service in question *only allows PUT and PATCH* to create objects.

In that case using `replacingEntity()` (which translates to `PUT`) should already work with your code. You can make PATCH work as well by replacing the builder approach with a constructor call + setter approach.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @matkuhr. So the contact I am sending is brand new and doesn't exist in Marketing Cloud. When I call  `getContactOriginDataByKey()` I get a 404 so there's no entity to update. Perhaps I'm using the wrong service?

Comment: In that case what you want to do is create an entity first. If the service allows it you should have a `createContactOriginData(data)` method. 
If such a method doesn't exist chances are your service doesn't allow creating entities. You can check by looking into the service definition.

Comment: That makes sense. I was curious why I wasn't seeing a `create` option in my autocomplete, but looking closer in the service definition, sure enough... `<EntitySet Name="ContactOriginData" EntityType="API_MKT_CONTACT_SRV.ContactOriginData" sap:creatable="false" sap:deletable="false" sap:content-version="4"/>`. Thanks for the help! I'll look into this more to see what I need to do to allow creation of contacts.

Comment: So for kicks I forced it to `sap:creatable="true"` and after recompiling the create method showed up. However, I now get the error `HTTP Method 'POST' is not supported for OData service API_MKT_CONTACT_SRV`, which makes sense because I forced it.

Comment: As I've been reading through their documentation there appears to be a disconnect with their requirements and the SDK. According to [here](https://help.sap.com/viewer/0f9408e4921e4ba3bb4a7a1f75f837a7/2102.500/en-US/95f2c87395bb4dda905010423029c23e.html) and [here](https://help.sap.com/viewer/0f9408e4921e4ba3bb4a7a1f75f837a7/2102.500/en-US/66340fe5e8d84d02b21d3af04476b3f5.html) `PUT` & `PATCH` are both acceptable for creating new contacts and they actually recommend `PATCH` as a more universal method.

Comment: Thanks for providing the service info! That explains things. I expanded my answer how to enable `PATCH` for this scenario. However, `PUT` should work regardless. Can you check if it works as a stand alone request, outside of batch?
Or if you can get `PUT` to work via Postman? If so you could [enable HTTP wire logs](https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/java/guides/logging-overview#configuring-logback) to see & compare the exact request send out by the Cloud SDK to what you send in Postman.

Comment: @matkur, you sir are a scholar! I enabled the HTTP wire logs and found that my payload was an empty JSON object. The error message I was getting before now makes so much more sense. I followed your suggestion above and switched from the builder approach to the constructor + setter approach and it worked! In fact, this worked for both standalone and batch modes. Thank you so much for your help and patience!

Comment: Happy to hear that it solved your problem! If you see more strange behaviour (the service seems to be somewhat special among OData services) don't hesitate to reach out.